# HTML 5 full screen site exits full screen mode on internal links

Tags: html

I'm building a site using HTML 5 and want to have a full screen option. I've got it working using the below code, however when you click an internal link it exits full screen mode. This is rather undesirable. I've searched extensively and haven't seen any answers to this question, only to questions relating to webapps for iOS, which this is not.  Demo site is here: http://kvrm.co.uk/jw/

I've also noticed that when going fullscreen in Firefox a black band appears across the bottom of the screen, which does not happen in Chrome or Safari.

How can I keep the site in full screen mode while navigating to other internal pages? (Also, can anything be done about the black bar in Firefox?)

Here's the full screen code:

```
(function () {
var viewFullScreen = document.getElementById("view-fullscreen");
if (viewFullScreen) {
    viewFullScreen.addEventListener("click", function () {
        var docElm = document.documentElement;
        if (docElm.requestFullscreen) {
            docElm.requestFullscreen();
        }
        else if (docElm.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            docElm.mozRequestFullScreen();
        }
        else if (docElm.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
            docElm.webkitRequestFullScreen();
        }
    }, false);
}

var cancelFullScreen = document.getElementById("cancel-fullscreen");
if (cancelFullScreen) {
    cancelFullScreen.addEventListener("click", function () {
        if (document.exitFullscreen) {
            document.exitFullscreen();
        }
        else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
            document.mozCancelFullScreen();
        }
        else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
            document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
        }
    }, false);
}


var fullscreenState = document.getElementById("fullscreen-state");
if (fullscreenState) {
    document.addEventListener("fullscreenchange", function () {
        fullscreenState.innerHTML = (document.fullscreen)? "" : "not ";
    }, false);

    document.addEventListener("mozfullscreenchange", function () {
        fullscreenState.innerHTML = (document.mozFullScreen)? "" : "not ";
    }, false);

    document.addEventListener("webkitfullscreenchange", function () {
        fullscreenState.innerHTML = (document.webkitIsFullScreen)? "" : "not ";
    }, false);
}

var marioVideo = document.getElementById("mario-video")
    videoFullscreen = document.getElementById("video-fullscreen");

if (marioVideo && videoFullscreen) {
    videoFullscreen.addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
        if (marioVideo.requestFullscreen) {
            marioVideo.requestFullscreen();
        }
        else if (marioVideo.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            marioVideo.mozRequestFullScreen();
        }
        else if (marioVideo.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
            marioVideo.webkitRequestFullScreen();
            /*
                *Kept here for reference: keyboard support in full screen
                * marioVideo.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
            */
        }
    }, false);
}
```

})();

Comment: May I ask what benefit your users are getting from forcing their browser into full-screen mode? Barring a specific need, this is a violation of some pretty basic usability principles. (So you might be jumping through hoops only to diminish your users' experiences.)

Comment: The users aren't forced to use the full screen mode, it is just an option - to enter full screen you have to click a link that says "full screen".  I personally never use full screen and don't like the idea of it, however my client seems to think it is great and is unhappy with the above issues. If it were up to me I'd do away with it entirely...

Comment: Yeah, that's tough. Trying to educate clients is probably the hardest part of this job. Charge him by the hour!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an iframe. The outer page contains only the toggle fullscreen button and a large iframe that fills the rest of the screen and contains your real content. Your layout already has a clear space to the left of the toggle button so you won't even have to change your layout.

Navigation within the iframe, even to other domains, won't break fullscreen mode on the outer frame.

You need to be careful sizing the iframe so there's no scrollbar on the outer frame.

Comment: Thanks, I'd rather not use an iframe though, for various reasons. I think I'll convince the client to do away with the fullscreen option.