# Full screen html5 and opening another link

Tags: jquery, html, fullscreen

So I've made a fullscreen toggle button, but when I'm in fullscreen browsing mode and click another link the navigation bar appears.

Is there a way to keep the navigation bar hiden so that my visitor can browse full-screen through my site (when going to other internal links)?

I know I could use an iframe but I'd rather not.
(There is a similar question on stackoverflow, unanswered however
[HTML 5 full screen site exits full screen mode on internal links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12841018/html-5-full-screen-site-exits-full-screen-mode-on-internal-links) )

Cheers!

```
$('#fullscreen').toggle(
    function(){
        if (docElm.requestFullscreen) {
            docElm.requestFullscreen();
        }
        else if (docElm.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            docElm.mozRequestFullScreen();
        }
        else if (docElm.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
            docElm.webkitRequestFullScreen();
        }
        else if (docElm.msRequestFullScreen) {
            docElm.msRequestFullScreen();
        }
    },
    function(){
        if (document.exitFullscreen) {
            document.exitFullscreen();
        }
        else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
            document.mozCancelFullScreen();
        }
        else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
            document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears there is an event handler for this. Try:

```
document.addEventListener("fullscreenchange", function (e) { 
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

You'll of course need this to only apply when they haven't hit an "exit full screen button" or they'll be stuck.

Comment: Thanks Andrew! This does not however work when refreshing a page since the javascript can't stop the propagation then (I think it's a technical limitation with no solution). It does however work when I load my pages through ajax. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: I might. Do you have any event handlers attached to these links, and what browser are you using?

Comment: No I've got no event handers attached to the links, but I can add them. I tried chrome and safari.

Comment: This is odd - I feel like there must be something on the page forcing it to leave full screen. When browsing chrome in full screen normally, link-clicks don't force it out.

Comment: Hi andrew I was talking about the browser's addressbar etc that is coming up. The screen still stays fullscreen

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this. How are you changing the address (e.g. are you using `window.location.replace` or another method?).

Comment: I think in general with HTML5 full screen it's a bit different than manually activating full screen in subtle ways, and one of them is that navigating breaks full screen. Kind of makes sense because if you full screen on an element you dont know if that element will be on the next page. But it's an annoying experience for users.